# Can't open .jar file from ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, java

I have the Jodin3 jar file installed: `JOdin3CASUAL-r1035-dist.jar`. Can't open it.

- `java -jar JOdin3CASUAL-r1035-dist.jar` does not work: `Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application`
- `./JOdin3CASUAL-r1035-dist.jar` does not work: `invalid file (bad magic number): Exec format error`

java is installed. Oracle is installed. No need to update.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1101      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1101      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
```

What else do I need to open a file in ubuntu?

=============================================

```
sudo apt-get install openjfx
[sudo] password for xxx: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openjfx is already the newest version (11.0.2+1-1~18.04.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 123 not upgraded.
```

i have the jfx updated, thanks for trying!

I also tried this: https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/solved-running-jar-on-ubuntu-linux-18-04.93400/ without any success

Comment: Not being a Java user myself, I'm just noticing that you select a Java 8 runtime, while the JavaFX package has 11 in its version. What happens if you select the Java 11 runtime?

Comment: because the jar file is kinda old (2015) the java version that is suposed to open it is the 8 instead of the newest. A lot of programs still use the 8th version

Comment: Did you _try_ running with the Java 11 runtime? Are you able to install an older `openjfx`?

Comment: yes, just tried and the outcome was the same. Just so you don't think i'm making stuff up a few months ago I installed the 8 version because file wasn't opening with the 11-th one. It worked fine back then. For some classic misterious linux reason i can't simply open the file anymore. I miss windows sometimes

Comment: Your openjfx seems to be for Java 11, but Java 8 is your default runtime. Try with `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar JOdin3CASUAL-r1035-dist.jar`or try something like `sudo apt-get install openjfx=8.*`to install the Java 8 openjfx version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I needed Oracle's java 8. Which had it's license changed in April 16 of this year. So if others have this problem the answer is to visit Oracle's website and try to download the version from there

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `openjfx` JavaFX/OpenJFX package is missing.

You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install openjfx
```

Then try `java -jar JOdin3CASUAL-r1035-dist.jar` again.

Comment: it seems like i have that package, i edited my question to add the output of your command